# Invalid login when my credentials are right. VB.net MySQL login program

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Im currently working on a mysql login system in vb.net
Whenever i goto login i get a message that my login is invalid even though I know it is right.

My code:

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Login

    Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("connstringhere")

    ' show/hide password text 
    Private Sub CheckBoxSP_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBoxSP.CheckedChanged
        If PASSWORD.UseSystemPasswordChar = True Then
            ' show password
            PASSWORD.UseSystemPasswordChar = False
        Else
            ' hide password
            PASSWORD.UseSystemPasswordChar = True
        End If
    End Sub

    'button log in 
    Private Sub LOGINBUTTON_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LOGINBUTTON.Click
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT `Id`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `Id` = @username AND `password` = @password", connection)
        command.Parameters.Add("@username", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = USERNAME.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = PASSWORD.Text
        Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(command)
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        adapter.Fill(table)
        If table.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username Or Password")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Logged In")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Login_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Fixed it. The problem was with the database i wasnt spelling the db name right.

Comment: Back ticks are not all purpose MySQL delimiters.  Also, passwords should never be stored as plaintext.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT `Id`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `Id` = @username AND `password` = @password", connection)
```

You probaby need to change " 'Id' " to " 'username"

```
Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = @username AND `password` = @password", connection)
```

Id is usualy integer and you have char variable.